# Playing sound when ViewPager is swiped

Tags: android

How can I play a sound when the ViewPager is swiped? Where should I put the player code? The code I use for playing a sound sample is as follows:

```
   MediaPlayer mp;
   mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sample);
   mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           mp.reset();
           mp.release();
           mp=null;
       }
   });
   mp.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where should I put the player code?

`ViewPager` gives you the possibility to register an instance of a class that extends the interface `OnPageChangeListener`, which contains three callbacks:

- `onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)`
- `onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)`
- `onPageSelected(int position)`

you could run it when `onPageSelected` is invoked